# getting ConcurrentModificationException from Android OS itself?

Tags: android, screen-rotation

### Background

I've found out that when I start my app on landscape mode and soon after I rotate to portrait mode, I get the next weird log:

```
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.remove(HashMap.java:824)
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.applyConfigurationToResourcesLocked(ActivityThread.java:4096)
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:4159)
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1436)
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

after this error appears, my app crashes.

### The problem

This doesn't always occur, but it also doesn't show where exactly is the problem. none of the classes that are shown here belongs to my app.

At first I thought it has something to do with the fact I have "Xposed" framework installed, but i'm not sure that's the reason (the bug is quit rare).

### The question

has anyone else got this error?

What does it occur?

How come I can't see where the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the framework, the logout output specifies it in the line:

> 01-25 02:34:25.253: E/AndroidRuntime(26485):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)

This error usually happens when two threads try to modify a collection items at the same time when the collection is being used, for example, if you try to remove an element of a list that is currently being fetched using for(Object object: yourtList), and since it happens after configuration changes, I'm pretty sure they are modifying a list that is being used by the time that happens, also that covers the fact that it doesn't happen all the time.

Hope it helps.

Regards!

Comment: that's what i was thinking, but i can't narrow down what causes it within the framework. the bug is quite rare. also, the xposed framework part is written at the bottom of the log, so it's weird (usually errors are on the top of the log).

Comment: it is, is telling you that at it happened when tried to remove an element from hashmap java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.remove(HashMap.java:824), that hashmap was being used somewhere else at that time...

Comment: well all i know is that i've tried to disable the framework and couldn't reproduce it. then i also tried to enable it and enable a few modules (and restarting each time), trying to find which module is the problematic one (like a binary search), and didn't come with anything. i've even enabled all modules and still nothing. it's very rare so i can't find out what causes it, only that whatever causes it is probably hosted by this framework...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that somewhere in your `onCreate()` method, which is called when you have a runtime configuration change like landscape to portrait and viceversa, there is a `HashMap` where you're inserting/deleting/iterating over its values. As you've not pasted your code, I can't know it, but there might also be a loop where you both iterate and insert/delete items, which might lead to that ConcurrentModificationException too. Or a `Thread` working in background that is also accessing that `HashMap` at the same time you're iterating/inserting/deleting over it.

If the loop is your case, remember to not modify the `HashMap` inside the loop - Keep an additional datastructure where you save the values you want to insert/delete and do it outside the loop.

Maybe [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) might help.

Comment: thing is that the activity has this in the manifest: android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" , so it doesn't get destroyed when rotating the screen. not only that , but i use a single-threaded asyncTask , which will cancel the previous one if it's created more than once...

Comment: Seems weird. I've always read that the configChanges you're running is a last resource hack and should be avoided when possible (you might find it in the link I provided too, just Ctrl+f and search for **Note**), I don't know if maybe just because this kind of behaviors it's discouraged (I haven't experienced any anomalous behavior in my codes though). I've read in the other comment you can't reproduce it again, but as you know where the error is, I'd use `synchronized` on any of your HashMap operations to help you debug what can be going wrong.

Comment: I also don't think I use any HashMaps on this activity.